# Using SSIS and the KingswaySoft with OR filter condition getting timeout

Tags: filter, ssis, conditional-statements, kingswaysoft

Using SSIS and the KingswaySoft with OR filter condition getting timeout as in the below shown error message.

SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Dynamics CRM Source returned error code 0xC02090F5

Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException: CRM service call returned an error: The database operation timed out; this may be due to a computed column being used in a filter condition. Please consider removing filter conditions on computed columns, as these filter conditions are expensive and may cause timeouts. (Error Code: -2147187340, Detail Message: The database operation timed out; this may be due to a computed column being used in a filter condition. Please consider removing filter conditions on computed columns, as these filter conditions are expensive and may cause timeouts.) (SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics 365, v21.2.0.31501 - ISServerExec, v14.0.3356.20)System.ServiceModel.FaultException<KingswaySoft.DynamicsCrmServices.Soap2011.OrganizationService.OrganizationServiceFault>

: The database operation timed out; this may be due to a computed column being used in a filter condition. Please consider removing filter conditions on computed columns, as these filter conditions are expensive and may cause timeouts.".

Below is the filter condition getting timeout

```
    `<filter type='or'>
        <condition attribute='col1' operator='ge' value='@[User::InputToken1]' />
        <condition attribute='col2' operator='le' value='29'/>
        <condition attribute='col3' operator='le' value='29'/>
     </filter> `
```

Tried increasing the timeout from 2 minutes to 4 minutes, but still getting the same error message.

Expecting how to improve this filter condition so that it will complete it in less than 3 or 4 minutes.

Comment: Thank you for choosing KingswaySoft as your integration solution. For this requirement, please reach out to us at www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us with more details regarding this issue, and we will be happy to assist you.